# How do I create a oneToMany relationship between two Mongoose schemas?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two models each in their own js file within the same directory. One is called Place (for a travel bucket list app) and one is called Country. Country has the URL of an image of its flag as the key flagURL. I want to populate Place's "flag" key with the value of flagURL from Country. What would be the best way to do this?

Place model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const placeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    city: String,
    country: String,
    img: String, // this is for an image of the place, not the flag
    flag: 'flagImg URL Here',
    visited: Boolean,
});

const Place = mongoose.model('Place', placeSchema);

module.exports = Place;
```

Country model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const countrySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    countryName: String,
    countryCode: String,
    flagImg: String
});

const Country = mongoose.model('Country', countrySchema);

module.exports = Country;
```

Thanks for the help on my beginner question!

Comment: how is Place referencing the country? By which path in the Country schema? `countryName` or `countryCode` or maybe even `_id`? It's not clear because it just says `country` in `placeSchema`.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to reference the country schema in your place schema (so as to get the country associated with that particular place).

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const placeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    city: String,
    img: String, // this is for an image of the place, not the flag
    visited: Boolean,
    country: {
      type:mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, 
      ref: 'Country',
      required: [true, 'A place must have a country']
     
 }
});

const Place = mongoose.model('Place', placeSchema);

module.exports = Place;
```

What the country property will do is give you access to all the values of the properties of the country schema related to a particular place.

Your payload will be like this:

```
{
  "city": "califonia",,
  "img": dafault.png, // this is for an image of the place, not the flag
  "visited": true,
  "country": {
     "countryName": "United States of America",
     "countryCode": US,
     "flagImg": dafault.png, // the country's flag
  }
}
```